# Add space after array object in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm mapping an array in React where I'm outputting tags that are held in an array. I've got commas after every object, but would like a space as well.

Here is the mapping code:

```
{
    result &&
        result.map(project => {
            if (project.item) project = project.item;
            return (
                <ProjectStyling key={project.id}>
                    <h4>Project Tags:</h4>
                    <p>{(project ? " " : ", ") + project.keywords}</p>
                </ProjectStyling>
            );
        });
}
```

At the moment it looks like "Bob,Foo,Bar" where I want it to look like "Bob, Foo, Bar"

Note there is already a space after the comma in the jsx

Comment: I don't understand--you're saying `project.keywords` is an array and you want to control how they're displayed?

Comment: Yes, I want spaces to be there after every array element

Comment: Then do something with them, don't just rely on the default string representation of a JS array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's showing up without spaces because that's the default string representation of an array. You can use the *join* function to join each element with whatever separator you want.

In your case, I think a comma followed by a space is what you want.

```
<h4>Project Tags:</h4>
<p>{project.keywords.join(', ')}</p>
```